# How can I read a IBM WebSphere MQ message of format type MQEVENT in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I can get the event messages from the queue. I get the message properties. I am pretty sure the MQEVENT type is in PCF format but I cannot seem to find any good documentation on how to take that message and convet it into human readable format.

AccountingToken
ApplicationIdData
ApplicationOriginData
BackoutCount           0
BackoutCount           0
CharacterSet           437
CompletionCode         0
CorrelationId          System.Byte[]
DataLength             236
DataOffset             0
Encoding               546
Expiry                 -1
Feedback               0
Format                 MQEVENT
GroupId                System.Byte[]
MessageFlags           0
MessageId              System.Byte[]
MessageLength          236
MessageSequenceNumber  1
MessageType            8
Offset                 0
OriginalLength         -1
Persistence            0
Priority               0
PutApplicationName     NTPMFG01
PutApplicationType     7
PutDateTime            3/19/2010 10:29:08 PM
ReasonCode             0
ReasonName             MQRC_OK
ReplyToQueueManagerNameNTPMFG01
ReplyToQueueName
Report                 0
TotalMessageLength     236
UserId
Version                1

And here is the message.
   $   ?   -   ?   ?        ?   ?   D   ¯      0   MFG01                                        ?   D   -      0   MF
G.CUST.CAT                                    ?   ?   #   ¤   ?   ?   $   ?   ?   ?   %       ?   ?   &   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (myMQMessage.Format.CompareTo(MQC.MQFMT_EVENT) == 0)
I think it needs to be processed twice.
First process the PCF header with MQCFH

```
BuildMQCFH(new IBM.WMQ.PCF.MQCFH(myMQMessage));

public void BuildMQCFH(IBM.WMQ.PCF.MQCFH eventMessageHeader) {
  int reasonForEvent = eventMessageHeader.Reason;
}
```

Then you MUST reset the DataOffset to 0

```
myMQMessage.DataOffset = 0;
```

Second process the PCF parameters with PCFParameter.
BuildPcfMessage(new IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage(myMQMessage));

```
public void BuildPcfMessage(IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage pcfMessage) {
  IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFParameter[] pcfParameters = pcfMessage.GetParameters();
  afflictedQueueManager = pcfParameters[0].GetValue().ToString();
  afflictedQueue = pcfParameters[1].GetValue().ToString();
}
```

MQMessage, PCF.PCFMessage and MQCF each do a readbyte(s) moving the offset with out resetting afterwards.